# equivalence class problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have a question about "equivalence class" I don't know how to approach the question , proving that something is an equivalence relation is ok but i do not understand the equivalence class part.
my question is  : [image]

*the first part was to prove only one of them is an equivalence relations and it was easy to show that R isnt because it is not symmetric

*but the second question was to show the equivalence classes and i don't even have the slightest idea on how to approach it.. i was told that it is {1,3,9},{2,6},{4},{5},{7},{8}, but i do not know how they got there

thank you all for any type of help , stay safe!

Comment: Every equivalence class is characterized by containing exactly one number that isn't a multiple of $3$, and its product with powers of $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** let $[\,x\,]$ denote the equivalence class of $x$, then $y\in[\,x\,]$ if and only if $y\,R\,x$.

Can you prove that, for example, $1\,R\,3$ and $1\,R\,9$ but $1\,\not R\,2$, $1\,\not R\,4$, etc.?

Comment: thank you for the hint , i think what i understood was that the equivalence class of [1] for example is {1,3,9} because 1 stands with 3 and 9? so 1/3 is 3^-1 and -1 is an integer so it matches what they demand but for 1/2 it doesnt. but what i still dont understand is the rest of the classes like 4 5 7 8, i am sorry for these type of questions i spent hours trying to understand with no success

Comment: @Adamrk yes! And $1/9$ is $3^{-2}$. But no $j$ exists such that $1/2$ or  $1/4$ or $1/5$ or $1/6$ or $1/7$ or even $1/8$ are $3^j$. Comment again if you need!!

Comment: thank you so much!! i really appreciate it , just one last question for the rest of the classes , we also mentioned {4},{5},{7},{8} because of the reason that in equivalence classes the union has to be the whole set? thank you again

Comment: @Adamrk indeed $2R6$, but each of $4,5,7,8$ is only in relation to itself. So, $\{1,3,9\}\cup \{2,6\}\cup \{4\}\cup \{5\}\cup \{7\}\cup \{8\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Comment: thanks to you i finally understood something i spent all day on with no success ! but now its finally ok!